# How Do I Get The Leaderstats Cash Value In Zendov's Tycoon Kit

Tags: roblox

I Was Making Twitter Code Thing Like To Reedem Codes And I Want To Add Cash To Their  Value When They Reedem The Code To Do That I Need To Access The Leadersats Cash Value But I Don't Know How

I Tried To Look Up In Everysingle Code

Answer (score 0):

`leaderstats` is a folder located in `game.Players[PlayerName]`. To change a value in there get the player (there are lots of ways to get the player) and do:

```
player.leaderstats.Cash.Value += CashAmount
```

This will add the cash amount you input in `CashAmount` to the amount of cash the player currently has.